# React re-renders entire list when one item is changed

Tags: reactjs, render, state

I have a simple react app that renders the name and price of 5000 products. The price is editable and upon change the price is reflected in the state.

https://github.com/TonyCaffer/thinking-in-react-1

[image]

App.js manages the state and handles the price change via the onChangePrice function, which is passed down to ProductTable and to each ProductRow

I use immutability-helpers and I specifically change only the state record for the changed product.

But on each change there is a noticable one second lag because React is re-rendering all products. Each product has a key property which I thought would help React only re-render the necessary components.

In a production build it is less laggy but all products are re-rendered which is the root problem I'm trying to fix.

Why are all product components re-rendered? Is it because I pass this.state.products through the high level ProductTable thus triggering a total redraw of the list? If so how can each ProductRow manage its own record's state when the state is in a list?

Comment: It won't stop the re-rendering. They 'key' thing will call the same component which was called earlier, and call `componentWillUpdate` instead of `componentWillMount`. To stop rendering use `shouldComponentUpdate` to stop re-rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React schedules updates in two phases: reconciler phase (or also render phase since it involves the render method for the components we define) and the commit phase. When the state is updated React will initiate the update process no matter what. It is the use of appropriate shouldComponentUpdate that can help you reduce number of updates in the children components

Possible solution: Use a `shouldComponentUpdate` for `ProductRow`, that looks like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (
    this.props.guid !== nextProps.guid
    || // similarly check if the other new props are different
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false
}
```

The above check will make sure when parent detects a setState and schedules an update in the new React Fiber's work loop, not recomputation of the child component is undertaken and commit phase skip any DOM update altogether.

[Lin Clark explains the two phases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs) really well. It'll definitely help you understand how React Fiber manages updates.

You could look into [React Virtualised](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List) to improve perceived perf with extremely long lists.

Comment: I added a componentShouldUpdate function. Now updates are laggy in dev but there is no lag on production. I'll consider this a good result and make sure to architect my apps to never have such large lists. I wanted to push the limits of React before I commit to it.

Comment: See the updated github : https://github.com/TonyCaffer/thinking-in-react-1